# Is $\pi$ related to gravity?

Tags: pi, correlation

A friend of mine has a t-shirt that says $π^2 = g$. I told him that the fact that $3.14$ squared gives $9.8596$ and earth gravity is approximately $9.8$ is just a coincidence, he agreed with me, but what if there was an actual correlation?

Comment: Since pi is constant and cannot be regarded as square of non constant number or variable I.e. acceleration due to gravity. $\pi^2$ is numerically close to the value of g in $m/s^2$, but they have nothing to do with each other: it is an entirely accidental coincidence.

Comment: See [Why is $g$ so close to $\pi^2$?](https://physicsnapkins.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/why-is-g-so-close-to-%CF%80-squared/)

Comment: We know that the globally-average value of the gravitational acceleration on Earth’s surface can be obtained by the following formula :$$g=\dfrac{GM}{R^2}$$where $\;G\simeq6.674\cdot10^{-11}\,\text{Nm}^2/\text{ kg}^2\,$ is the Universal Gravitational Constant, $\,M\simeq5.972\cdot10^{24}\text{ kg}\,$ is the mass of Earth and $\,R\,$ is the globally-average value of the radius of Earth which is usually considered to be approximately $\,6,371,000\,$ metres.$\\ \\$ Since $\;g\simeq\pi^2\,\text{m}\,/\,\text{sec}^2\,$ and $\,g=\dfrac{GM}{R^2}\,,\,$ it follows that
$$\pi R\simeq\sqrt{GM}\;\;.$$

Comment: Therefore the distance between a place on Earth’s surface and its antipode is approximately equal to $\,\sqrt{GM}\,$ metres.$\qquad\\$ Hence, if there was an actual correlation between the globally-average value of the gravitational acceleration on Earth’s surface and $\,\pi^2\,,\,$ the distance between a place on Earth’s surface and its antipode would be approximately a function of $\,M\,$ which is the mass of Earth.